# Need a regex pattern for input validation

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex use in Java. I want to validate the input in the text box.

The input in the text box can start with any lowercase alphabet.
But it should not start with dm e.g. dmemployee. Whereas mdemployee will work.
The first character d can be followed by either digit or lowercase character (except m).

Please suggest a regex for this.

Thanks!

Comment: For a question like this, you really must supply some sample inputs that should match, and some that should not match. Otherwise, there's no way to help you properly. We're just guessing at what you need. Some people have supplied answers, but they're taking their best shot given the absence of information available.

Comment: Yes Alan.. I should have given sample inputs and outputs.. I found the answers to be helpful.. Based on the answers, i got the clue to generate regex suitable to my requirement..

Comment: I'm glad the ideas in the answers helped you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a negative lookahead. Also, your description is a bit confusing. Can this be all numbers and lowercase letters or only lowercase letters with `d` being allowed to be followed by numbers?

This regex assumes any mix of lowercase letters and numbers (disallowing `dm`)

```
/^(?!dm)[a-z0-9]+$/
```

Ah perfect. The other answer here would be if numbers can only follow an initial `d`

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!dm)(d[a-z0-9]|[a-ce-z])[a-z]*$
```

or use explicit (longer, but easier to understand):

```
^(d[a-ln-z0-9]|[a-ce-z])[a-z]*$
```